# Auto increment function does not accept 0 as starting number

Tags: php, while-loop

I created a small function that helps me build an array (i use it to populate a select2 element). It works great but it doesn't accept 0 as the starting number.

Although it is not really crucial i would really want to understand why this happens and how to fix it.

Here is the function:

```
function create_numstring_array($startNum, $endNum, $jumps, $sideString = NULL) {
    if($startNum && $endNum) {
        $data = array();
        $counter = intval($startNum);
        while($endNum > $counter ) {
            $data["$counter"] = $counter.' '.$sideString;
            $counter = $counter + $jumps;
            // echo $counter."<br />";
        }
        return $data;
    }
}


/*  DOESNT WORK
echo '<pre>Code:'."<br />";
print_r(create_numstring_array(0, 9, 0.5, ''));
echo '</pre>'."<br />";
*/



/*  WORKS! */
echo '<pre>Code:'."<br />";
print_r(create_numstring_array(1, 9, 0.5, ''));
echo '</pre>'."<br />";
```

I guess it gets stuck in this part

```
while($endNum > $counter) {
```

Since `$counter = 0` but how can i overcome this?

Comment: The error is before the while. Error : `if($startNum && $endNum)`, if `$startNum = 0`, then the test fail since (bool)0 mean false.

Comment: The last column in the first table on the [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) page should make it clear why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `(bool)0 == False`. So, your code fails, because you are testing $startNum and it is treated as boolean false.

Change it to something more reasonable, for example: `if (is_int($startNum) ...` or functions like that (`is_numeric` could be candidate)

Comment: Thank you - is_int did the trick ;) - somehow i think about that if condition in the start - crazy me. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
function create_numstring_array($startNum, $endNum, $jumps, $sideString = NULL){
    #check for valid input 
    #(can be float or integer so lets end always greater than start)
    if($startNum>$endNum || !is_numeric($jumps)) {
           return null;
    }
    #create the range
    $keys = range($startNum, $endNum, $jumps);
    #create values with or without sideString
    $values = ($sideString) 
            ? array_map(function($a) use ($sideString){ return $a.' '.$sideString;},$keys) 
            : $keys;
    #return the new array
    return array_combine($keys,$values);
}


echo '<pre>Code:'."<br />";
print_r(create_numstring_array(0, 9, 0.5, ''));
echo '</pre>'."<br />";
```

Why your version is not working, is explained in the comments, so here a working version, that check for valid input and valid jumbs. (Works with float and integer). Remove/Skipp last and first entry is they are not needed.